# Can I use refs in render?

Tags: reactjs

The following code obviously doesn't work
But the Idea is, I would like to conditional rendering depending on a child component's clientHeight, not sure if it's possible

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.comp = {};
    this.state = {
      clientHeight: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.comp)
    this.setState({
      clientHeight: this.comp.clientHeight
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} ref={comp => this.comp = comp}/>
        {
          this.state.clientHeight > 100 ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why not ? haven't you tried running this ??

Comment: Because if `<Hello />` get changed (size) the clientHeigh will not be accurate, I will have only previous values

Comment: ok you mean the changes occuring after the first render.... maybe do it conditionally inside `componentDidUpdate` ?

Comment: can you should an example please?

Comment: can you create a loading state, and mount CompA and B with opacity 0, check the height when ComponentDidMount and update loading state, then conditionally render the Comp

Comment: Turn out @Dane 's suggestion helped me, I posted as an answer, but I'm not sure if there is a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out @Dane's idea helped me. with `componentDidUpdate` hook. this achiever what I want, but it renders twice every time, one for the ref to be assigned, and change update to the new clientHeight, then render again base on the new clientHeight. Not sure if there is a better way.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.comp = {};
    this.state = {
      clientHeight: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
      if(prevProps !== this.props){
        this.setState({
          clientHeight: this.comp.clientHeight
        })
      }
    } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} ref={comp => this.comp = comp}/>
        {
          this.state.clientHeight > 100 ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work, but you don't actually care when `props` change, you only want to change `clientHeight` when your component resizes. You can do this with an [`onresize`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) handler that only calls `setState` if `this.comp.clientHeight` is different than your stored value.

Comment: Or you can use [`react-measure`](https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure) for this.

Comment: actually I do care the props change, otherwise it will end up with infinite loop :s

Comment: Yes, you do care, but you don't care to update this portion of the state in response to props changing. So, put the logic in an `onresize` callback _instead_ of in `componentDidUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by setting `clientHeight` value from `<Hello/>` component

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clientHeight: 0
    };
  }

  handler(newSize) {
      this.setState({
          clientHeight: newSize
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} onResize={this.handler}/>
        {
          this.state.clientHeight > 100 ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

you can get window height by `window.addEventListener('resize', ((c)=>{console.log(window.innerHeight)}));`

Comment: But I would like to render the App component again with the new clientHeight, not just console.log it

Comment: Instead of calling `console.log` call `this.props.onResize`. Since that event is on the `window`, though, your specific component might not have resized. You could attach the event listener to your component with [`onresize`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) and then check whether the `event.target`'s height has changed.

Comment: Yes, you could add an id to the child element and get his actual height with `const height = document.getElementById('content').clientHeight;` this will have to be done in `componentDidMount`